# Child not reading output from another child that put it in the pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, child-process

I've been working on this school assignment forever now, and I'm super close to finishing.

The assignment is to create a bash shell in C, which sounds basic enough, but it has to support piping, IO redirect, and flags within the piped commands. I have it all working except for one thing; the | piping child isn't getting any of the data written to the pipe by the user command process child. If I were to remove the child fork for pipechild, and have everything from if(pipe_cmd[0] != '\0') run as the parent, it would work just fine (minus ending the program because of execlp). If I were to use printf() inside the pipe section, the output would be in the right file or terminal, which just leaves the input from the user command process child not getting to where it needs to be as a culprit.

Does anyone see an issue on how I'm using the pipe? It all felt 100% normal to me, given the definition of a pipe.

```c
        int a[2]; 
        pipe(a);
        //assume file_name is something like file.txt
        strcat(file_name, "file.txt");
        strcat(pipe_cmd, "wc");
        if(!fork()) 
        { 
            if(pipe_cmd[0] != '\0') // if there's a pipe
            {
                close(1); //close normal stdout
                dup(a[1]); // making stdout same as a[1] 
                close(a[0]); // closing other end of pipe 
                execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
            }
            else if(file_name[0] != '\0') // if just a bare command with a file redirect
            {
                int rootcmd_file = open(file_name, O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
                dup2(rootcmd_file, STDOUT_FILENO);
                execlp("ls","ls",NULL); // writes ls to the filename
            }
            // if no pipe or file name write... 
            else if(rootcmd_flags[0] != '\0') execlp("ls","ls",NULL)
            else execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
        } else wait(0);
        
        if(pipe_cmd[0] != '\0') // parent goes here, if pipe. 
        { 
            pipechild = fork();
            if(pipechild != 0) // *PROBLEM ARISES HERE- IF THIS IS FORKED, IT WILL HAVE NO INFO TAKEN IN.
            { 
                close(0); // closing normal stdin
                dup(a[0]); // making our input come from the child above
                close(a[1]); // close other end of pipe
                if(file_name[0] != '\0') // if a filename does exist, we must reroute the output to the pipe
                {
                    close(1); // close normal stdout
                    int fileredir_pipe = open(file_name, O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
                    dup2(fileredir_pipe, STDOUT_FILENO); //redirects STDOUT to file
                    execlp("wc","wc",NULL); // this outputs nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    // else there is no file. 
                    // executing the pipe in stdout using execlp.
                    execlp("wc","wc",NULL); // this outputs nothing

                }
            }
            else wait(0);
        }
```

Thanks in advance. I apologize for some of the code being withheld. This is still an active assignment and I don't want any cases of academic dishonesty. This post was risky enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, without a [mre], nobody will be able to determine what's going on. The key parts are the ones that are not shown.

Comment: I followed part 2 of that, but I can attempt to make a second bit of code if needed. I removed the child fork() code for the pipechild and ran without that, and for some reason, it worked just fine (minus the fact that execlp() killed the program as it should). I'm a little new to this, is that not enough information?

Comment: Sorry, it's not. Unless anyone in the world is able to cut/paste the shown code, ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem, it is not a [mre]. Until you answer "yes" to the following question: can I cut/paste only what's in a question into a new file, compile, run and get the same problem -- until the answer to this question is "yes" it is not a [mre].

Comment: Alright, it's edited to work. It should run "ls | wc" but the "wc" part gets no input from the "ls" part. Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: This is still not a [mre], since cut/pasting ***exactly what's shown*** doesn't have a chance of compiling. No include files. No `main`, etc... Still, it's now obvious enough what's broken here...

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Pay attention to both the *minimal* part and *reproducible* part. Minimal means that it doesn't contain any code that is not needed to reproduce the problem. Your code as posted contains a dozen cases of different parameter combinations. We only need one, specifically, the one that doesn't work. Remove all the rest. Reproducible means that it contains all the code needed to reproduce the problem. And all means all. Can you submit your homework without `main` and `#include`s and stuff? Same here.

Answer (score 0):

```
} else wait(0);
```

The shown code `fork`s the first child process and then `wait`s for it to terminate, at this point.

The first child process gets set up with a pipe on its standard output. The pipe will be connected to the second child process's standard input. The fatal flaw in this scheme is that the second child process isn't even started yet, and won't get started until the first process terminates.

Pipes have limited internal buffering. If the first process generates very little output chances are that its output will fit inside the tiny pipe buffer, it'll write its output and then quietly terminate, none the wiser.

But if the pipe buffer becomes full, the process will block and wait until something reads from the pipe and clears it. It will wait as long as it takes for that to happen. And wait, and wait, and wait. And since the second child process hasn't been started yet, and the parent process is waiting for the first process to terminate it will wait, in vain, forever.

This overall logic is fatally flawed for this reason. The correct logic is to completely `fork` and execute ***all*** child processes, close the pipe descriptors in the parent (this is also important), and then `wait` for ***all*** child processes to terminate. `wait` must be the very last thing that happens here, otherwise things will break in various amazing and mysterious ways.

Comment: I think I'm a little confused. So what you're saying is it's technically impossible for me to use the pipe as a buffer (albeit not a good idea)? Either that or I should fork() the second child above the fork() for the first child, and use those guard `if` statements to make sure the flow of execution runs the first child, then the second after not waiting for the first to finish? I tried the latter and that did the exact same thing as normal.

Comment: I think I was fairly clear that relying on the size of a pipe's internal buffer is, well, a pipe dream. I don't know what else you tried, or didn't try. I can only know what's shown in the question, and this is an obvious flaw in the shown code. Furthermore, it doesn't matter which process gets `fork`ed first. Nothing in my answer suggested that the issue is the relative order of `fork`ing. Finally, once both processes are `fork`ed there's nothing that the parent process can do to control the "flow of execution" to run one or the other child. They are now independent processes.

Comment: I figured that was the case, but you said the correct logic was to fork and execute all child processes, so I assumed that the order of forking mattered. Regardless this sadly isn't working now that I think I understand (and still has the same issue as before), but thanks anyways for looking.
EDIT: changed the fork to the top (was smarter to do that anyways), removed all else waits until the end of the code execution. Still having same issue. Can't minimally reproduce the issue either, when I try it by itself with all the same IO redirection it works fine. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Looks like you were right. But I can't remove that one wait command. If I do, then the shell command prompt won't print correctly. I guess I'll have to refactor my code entirely. Not looking to do that so I may accept that it "works" but not perfectly.

Comment: I explicitly explained: "`wait` for all child processes to terminate". Nobody said about removing any `wait` call. Just that all `wait`ing must happen after `fork`ing all child processes.

Comment: That's what it is doing as it sits, isn't it? There are 2 child processes that are spawned. The other case is `else wait()` for the parent. I guess what you want me to do is wait for *both* to terminate in the same wait command? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Yes, and when you `wait` for the first child process to terminate it "sits" and waits for it to terminate, before starting the second child process. As Mr. Spock would describe this approach: this is not logical. And nowhere did I mention "the same wait command". You use the wait command to wait for both child processes to terminate, but wait waits for one process at a time.